Making a node in TikZ occupy the vertical space of one line - at least as far as positioning a "pin" is concerned
In the following code for a diagram, I have a "pin" draw from the vertex of a parabola. I would like it drawn to the middle of the node as if "V = (0,0)" were not in the node.
Here is the code.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=4 5,
    xmin=-9,xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=7,
    restrict y to domain=-6:7,
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none
]

%The following plot is that of a parabola. Its focus is located and its directrix is drawn.
\addplot[samples=501, domain={-2*(1+sqrt(6))}:{2*(sqrt(6)-1)}] {-1/4*(x+2)^2 + 3};
\addplot [samples=2, dashed, latex-latex, domain=-5:7] (-2,x);


\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-9:5] {4};
\coordinate (label for directrix) at (5.15,4);
\path node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0] at (label for directrix){$\ell$};


\coordinate (F) at (-2,2);
\coordinate (P) at (2,-1);
\node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] at (P){$P = (x,y)$};


\coordinate (V) at (-2,3);


\end{axis}




\draw[fill] (F) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (an_end_of_a_pin) at ($(F) +(225:{4/3})$);
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (F) -- (an_end_of_a_pin) node[anchor=north, align=center, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0]{Focus\\$F$};


\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);


\node[overlay,text width=0.4\linewidth, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.east) +(1,0)$){$P$ is an arbitrary point that is equidistant from $F$ and $\ell$};


\coordinate (end_of_a_pin_from_Vertex) at ($(V) +({-4/3},0)$);
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (V) -- (end_of_a_pin_from_Vertex) node[anchor=east, align=center, inner sep=0]{Vertex of the parabola\\{$V = (0,0)$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}


Please provide a sketch of desired result. Your code generate (to my opinion) a bit unusual result  ...

Like this?

\documentclass[border=120pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[height=5in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=4 5,
    xmin=-9,xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=7,
    restrict y to domain=-6:7,
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none
    ]
    \addplot[samples=501, domain={-2*(1+sqrt(6))}:{2*(sqrt(6)-1)}] {-1/4*(x+2)^2 + 3};
    \addplot [samples=2, dashed, latex-latex, domain=-5:7] (-2,x);
    \addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-9:5] {4};
    \coordinate (label for directrix) at (5.15,4);
    \path node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0] at (label for directrix){$\ell$};
    \coordinate (F) at (-2,2);
    \coordinate (P) at (2,-1);
    \node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] at (P){$P$};
    \coordinate (V) at (-2,3);
    
  \end{axis}
  
  \draw[fill] (F) circle (1.5pt);
  \coordinate (an_end_of_a_pin) at ($(F) +(225:{4/3})$);
  \draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (F) -- (an_end_of_a_pin) node[anchor=north, align=center, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0]{Focus\\$F$};
  
  \draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[dash dot] (F) -- (P);
  
  \node[overlay,text width=0.4\linewidth, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.east) +(1,0)$){$P$ is an arbitrary point that is equidistant from $F$ and $\ell$};
  
  \coordinate (end_of_a_pin_from_Vertex) at ($(V) +({-4/3},0)$);
  \draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (V) -- (end_of_a_pin_from_Vertex) node (a)[anchor=east, align=center, inner sep=0]{Vertex of the parabola};
    \node [anchor=north,inner ysep=.2\baselineskip] at (a.south) {$V = (0,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Alternatively, you could use a border anchor rather than east. For example,
  \draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (V) -- (end_of_a_pin_from_Vertex) node (a)[anchor=10, align=center, inner sep=0]{Vertex of the parabol\\$V = (0,0)$};



I see in your first code for the diagram that you had used inner ysep=.2\baselineskip to separate the node containing "Vertex of the parabola" from "V = (0,0)."

Is that the default interline spacing in text mode?

@user143462 I think so, but I cannot say that I checked. Also, it is font and font size dependent, so definitely a rough approximation. But that was what I was aiming for, yes.

You could use \phantom to make the node three lines and thereby match the exact vertical position as if it was only one line. Like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (-3,0) node[align=center, anchor=east]{\phantom{$V = (0,0)$}\\Vertex of the parabola\\$V = (0,0)$};
\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (-3,0) node[anchor=east]{Vertex of the parabola};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


